# Why might -exec affect the output of find in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

If I run this command...

```
sudo find /storage -name "*~" -or -name ".*~" -or -name "#.*#"
-or -name ".DS_Store" -or -name "Thumbs.db"
```

... it gives me a list of matching files, as expected. However, if I use this command...

```
sudo find /storage -name "*~" -or -name ".*~" -or -name "#.*#"
-or -name ".DS_Store" -or -name "Thumbs.db" -exec rm -v {} \;
```

... nothing is deleted. Similarly, with echo, nothing is printed...

```
sudo find /storage -name "*~" -or -name ".*~" -or -name "#.*#"
-or -name ".DS_Store" -or -name "Thumbs.db" -exec echo {} \;
```

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to group your expression correctly - currently the `-exec` only applies to the last `-or` branch.

```
sudo find /storage \( -name "*~" -or -name ".*~" -or -name "#.*#" -or -name ".DS_Store" -or -name "Thumbs.db" \) -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Just remember that `-exec` is just an expression that returns true if the command returns zero, so running the command is just a side-effect.

Comment: especially note the escaped parentheses `\(` and `\)` -- this prevents the shell from interpreting them; in this case you want `find` to handle them as part of the expression.  this and other good examples on the find manpage: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm

Comment: Seems my workaround wasn't necessary, works like a charm, cheers.

Comment: @Douglas Leeder - Came across this example that helped me answer my own question at http://superuser.com/questions/474439/find-missing-argument-to-exec-when-executing-the-find-command-in-linux however I don't quite follow the statement `so running the command is just a side-effect`. What do you mean by that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
find Documents/ -iname '*.txt' -exec echo {} \;
 -or -iname '*.cpp' -exec echo {} \;
```

This however works. Hope this can help you further a little. If you use exec separately with all -or's the command will work.

I've found an alternative to your problem though.

```
for file in $(find Documents/ -iname '*.txt' 
-or -iname '*.cpp'| awk '{print $1}'); do rm $file; done
```