# find: missing argument to `-exec' when executing the find command in Linux

Tags: linux, find

I get the error `find: missing argument to`-exec'` when I attempt to run the command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg \) -exec echo {} \;
```

The reason I am using `echo` is because I want to make sure it is returning the results I expect before I replace it with either `rm` or `mv`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try getting rid of the superfluous dot at the end?

Comment: @Sparr - Sorry added a period in the post as I ended my sentence. The period does not appear in the command I execute.

Comment: Running it on find version 4.4.2, I receive no error. It has successfully found the .png file.

Comment: @bbaja42 - I found the issue. I was using colons as opposed to a semi-colon in the command I was executing. The example I posted was typed out and not pasted so didn't have the actual error in my syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue apparently was I was using the `:` in my command as opposed to `;`. I noticed that as I repeated the exercise having read the example at [Why might -exec affect the output of find in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/95069/why-might-exec-affect-the-output-of-find-in-linux?rq=1).

The example I posted although real was typed out as opposed to copied and pasted.

Comment: I'm closing this because it's just a typo thing and thus not really reproducible for others – hope that's okay with you.

Comment: Right. There's no way we could have figured that out.

Comment: @slhck - That's okay. I only posted it so that if someone had a similar error, they would know what to look for.

Comment: @Michael Hampton - Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `-exec...` at all. Just run the command without it, and you will see what it found.

If it looks acceptable, add `-delete` onto the end to delete the files.

Comment: Great but I want to know how to use it with -exec. For example appending `-delete` would simply delete files but what if I wanted to move the files or something else.